# Copy constructor call C++

Tags: c++, abstract-class, copy-constructor

So I am quite confused about copy constructors in C++. I have the following code:

```
class creature   /* abstract class*/
{
    private:
        string name;
        int longevity;
        creature_society * cs;
    public:
        creature(int,int,int,creature_society*);
        //creature(const creature&);
        virtual ~creature();

        virtual int is_a_good() =0;
};

class good_creature : public creature
{
     public:
         good_creature(int,int,creature_society*);
         //good_creature(const good_creature&);
         ~good_creature();

         int is_a_good() //returns 1
};

class bad_creature : public creature
{
    public:
         bad_creature(int,int,creature_society*);
         //bad_creature(const bad_creature&);
         ~bad_creature();

          int is_a_good(void); //returns 0
}
```

So I have an abstract class called  `creature` , a  `good_creature`  and a  `bad_creature`  which are a children class of  `creature` .

At my program I also have an array called `society` which has type of `creature*` objects. If my creature through a condition is defined as good, I allocate space for it and store it in `society` array as `good_creature`. The same happens for bad creature. I construct it as described in the following code:

```
society = new creature*[M];
for(i=0;i<M;i++)
{
      if(condition)
            society[i] = new good_creature(L,good,this);
      else
            society[i] = new bad_creature(L,bad,this);
}
```

So I have to make a pure virtual function: `creature::clone(int position)` which if it's either a `good_creature` or a `bad_creature`, it has to delete the `society[pos]` and make a copy of the `society[pos-1]` through a **copy constructor**.

So for example my `good_creature::clone(int position)` is like this:

```
  void good_creature::clone(int position)
  {
      int cop_pos=position -1;     //getting the position before that in order to copy it
      delete society[pos];
      society[pos] = new good_creature( *society[cop_pos] ); 
      //....
   }
```

I get an error because `society[cop_pos]` is of type `creature*`. I tried casting it to good creature but unfortunately I keep getting errors. Is it because I am not calling the copy constructor right, is it because I am not casting right? Any ideas? This has been buffling me for 2 days. Keep in mind I' m a newbie and might have done something wrong.

Also I don't need to define my own copy constructor since all the elements in `society[i]` point at the same object that is defined by `creature_society * cs`, so I'm trying to use the default constructors since I do not need **deep copy**.

Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE**

A class I forgot to mention and the way I construct society

```
class creature_society
{
    private:
        int N; // number of the creatures we want to be made in society
        creature ** society;
    public:
        creature_society(int,int);
        ~creature_society();
 };
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your design. How do you know that `society[cop_pos]` is a `good_creature` and not a `bad_creature`?

Comment: Why do you need the clone function?

Comment: Where is the type `creature_society` defined ?

Comment: @Kevin I just gave an example of `good_creature::clone`. If its a `good_creature` or `bad_creature` is defined in another function. I have checked if `society[cop_pos]` is bad or good in another function.

Comment: @Q_M but in `good_creature::clone` you assume that `society[cop_pos]` is also a `good_creature`. How do you know that?

Comment: @erg It's a requirement of the exercise I have. It sends a `position`, deletes the `society[position]` and makes a copy of the previous element.

Comment: I think what you might want is to have the clone function return the cloned object (it can be a different function). Make it pure virtual and do something like: `society[pos] = society[cop_pos]->clone()`.

Comment: @Ilya I updated it as well as the constrction of society.

Comment: @Q_M: Okay. So, I would make a virtual function `clone(..)` that returns a `creature`. The implementation of `clone` in `good_creature` will create a new `good_creature` and the implementation in `bad_creature` a `bad_creature`.

Comment: @Kevin I forgot to mention I check if it's good or bad before calling `clone`.

Comment: Good polymorphic code uses virtual functions to have different behavior based on type. You shouldn't be checking the types yourself. Call a virtual function on the object instead of trying to cast it.

Comment: @Q_M: If both creatures implement a clone method, and the creature class has a pure virtual clone method, you can just call clone() on any creature and magically the program will call either the good or bad creature clone method, depending on the type of the object actually stored.

Comment: @erg Is there a way to fix this line `society[pos] = new good_creature( *society[cop_pos] );` in order to actually call the default copy constructor and not get an error?

Comment: @Q_M yes. Create a virtual function and call it on `society[cop_pos]` to return a cloned copy. If it's a bad_creature it will create a bad_creature. If it's a good_creature it will create a good_creature. If it's something else it will create something else.

Comment: @Kevin But I need to have a copy constructor to make the `society[pos]`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I'm making an answer for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't know if `society[cop_pos]` is the correct type, so you cannot safely cast. A better solution is to use a virtual function to create a copy

```
class creature {
public:
    virtual creature* clone() const = 0;
    ...
};
class good_creature {
public:
    good_creature* clone() { return new good_creature(*this); }
    ...
};
//Similar for bad_creature (and any other derived classes)
```

In your case you'd call it like this:
`society[pos] = society[cur_pos]->clone();`

There's no need to know the type of the object you're cloning. The virtual function call takes care of that for you. Note that `good_creature::clone` returns a `good_creature*` instead of a `creature*`. This is a valid overload. A virtual function overload is allowed to return a derived class. In this case you could have it return a `creature*` as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use polymorphism and virtual dispatch to do the work for you.

Define a clone virtual function in creature class.

```
class creature
{
    virtual creature * clone() = 0;
}
```

and then override it in children:

```
class good_creature: public creature
{
    virtual creature * clone() override
    {
        return new good_creature(*this);
    }
}
```

and similar for bad_creature.

Then use it:

```
society[pos] = society[pos - 1]->clone();
```

Side note: your design seems to influenced by languages like Java. This is not a (modern) C++-style. For example, in modern C++ ownership is better expressed by `unique_ptr` instead of pointers. This would make code cleaner and much safer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `society` is an array of `creature`, not of `good creature`, so the copy constructor doesn't apply.

You can define a constructor for `good_creature` and for `bad_creature` taking as argument a creature:

```
good_creature(const creature&);
```

Comment: There is no other way of using the default constructors? LIke using casts? Do I have to make my own nevertheless?

Comment: Yes, you could do:

`society[pos] = new good_creature( *(dynamic_cast<good_creature *>(society[cop_pos])) );`
but I don't suggest it, because what really `society[cop_pos]` is unknown, in more complex cases, this is the way to undefined behavior.

Comment: In my case I test if `society[cop_pos]` is a `good_creature` or a bad_creature` before sending it to my function. Your approach with this line `society[pos] = new good_creature( *(dynamic_cast<good_creature *>(society[cop_pos])) );` actually runs my program perfectly. Do you use `dynamic_cast` because we use the `new` operator? Can you elaborate on that? I would be thankful. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Dynamic cast is used to perform upcasting and safe downcasting, i.e. to determine if an object is of a specific type in the inheritance hierarchy. That means that it could return NULL if the casting doesn't succeed.
Dynamic casting could not cover all cases (if the pointed object is a bad creature, no good creature could be copied), so a better approach is to define a constructor taking creature as parameter.